# Rename Resource file in Project C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a multiple languages project ASP.Net. I use Resouce file for my project.

Now I use:

`Resource.lbltestenter`

But I want to change name from Resouce to Language:

`Language.lbltestenter`

But i don't know how do that? Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio? Maybe even with ReSharper?

Comment: It's just a class so you can rename it. But its a resource file not a language file so why do you want to do that

Comment: @J.N. yes, i use Visual studio.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Because i have 2 projects (A and B), and i use preference dll from project A for project B, but inside dll of project A have Resource file, when i call Resource in project B, it's always preference Resource of project A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments to your question you mentioned:

> Because i have 2 projects (A and B), and i use preference dll from project A for project B, but inside dll of project A have Resource file, when i call Resource in project B, it's always preference Resource of project A.

It is common to have the same class in multiple namespaces. All you have to do is to qualify your class name with the namespace:

```
Namespace.Resource = new Namespace.Resource();
```

If you do not want to type long namespace names, then use an alias for it like this:

```
// obviously do not call it A but give it a more meaningful name
using A = Company.MyCompany.Project;
```

Then you can just qualify it like this:

```
A.Resource = new A.Resource();
```

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) on `using` directive.